# Table Structure to Store Data from Dynamic Forms

Tags: dynamic-data, formbuilder

We have a Form Builder (web) application which allows users to design their forms dynamically. What could be best table structure to store the data submitted through these dynamically created forms?

I am thinking of attribute_name and attribute_value kind of thing? Are there any better alternatives any suggestion to be flexible enough with these two column structure?

Comment: I am also trying to build a custom formbuilder for my app.  Can i as if you have any references to doing this.  I want to do something like Wufoo.com for my admin section. So i can easily build out multiple custom forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely take a look at Pivot Tables : as you suggest, essentially you have one table which defines the columns contained in a parent object, and  another table with an individual row for each attribute value.  For dynamic forms, then, as attributes are added, they become rows in a database, not columns.  Hope this helps.